# Data can't be copied to dataset in datagridview from treeview

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, treeview

I want to drop some data from treeview to the datagridview temporarily, but the datagrid view is already loaded some data from a xml file.

Someone Please explain to me the mechanism of this.

This is my drag/drop function: //It works perfectly if there is no data in the datagrid view.

```
  private void DataGridView1OnDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point dscreen = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        Point dclient = dataGridView1.PointToClient(dscreen);
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTest = dataGridView1.HitTest(dclient.X, dclient.Y);

        if (hitTest.ColumnIndex == 0 && hitTest.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            //dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(hitTest.RowIndex, "hitTest", "hitTest", "hitTest", "hitTest");
            var data = (object[]) e.Data.GetData(typeof(string[]));
            dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(hitTest.RowIndex, data);

        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }
```

For datagrid:

```
XmlReader xmlFile;
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("Product.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

For Treeview:

```
var filename = @"C:\Check.xml";
//First, we'll load the Xml document
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(filename);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the drag-drop-data to the control you should **add it to** the **datasource** of the control.

```
// will allow you to drop your data anywhere on gridview where a cell is
if (hitTest.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
{
   e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
   var data = (object[])e.Data.GetData(typeof(string[]));

   // causes error - if there is already data bound to the control
   //   see image below
   //dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(hitTest.RowIndex, data);

   DataTable dt = (DataTable) dataGridView1.DataSource;
   DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
   dr.ItemArray = data;
   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

*Error Message in DebugMode*

[image]

worked fine for me - if any error shows up in your code, let me know

Comment: It is a perfect solution. I have 2 more questions, 1.I can't drop anywhere in the datagridview. How can I drop it anywhere on the datagridview. 2. When i drop is it possible to check for the duplicate values?? Thank you.

Comment: edited answer, @your second question, how do you define a duplicate? what column(s) hasv to be checked?

Comment: You are great that's amazing. I want to check the second cell if it's already exists in the datagrid then display it. Thank you.